# How to fix Null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am writing an android application that consists of a alertdialog and i am getting a null pointer exception.I cant find any exceptions in my code but it was showing null pointer exception please tell me where i did the mistake

Here i used the library  downloaded from [here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) for material design for buttons here.this is my activity

```
package com.developer.milanandroid;


import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloatSmall;
import com.gc.materialdesign.widgets.SnackBar;
import com.milan.paperbuttons.signoutoptionsbuttons;

public class Modes extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPreferences";
     Button auto,manual,adminsettings;
     ActionBar action_bar;
     TextView welcome_headder;
     String welcome_headder_string;
     ButtonFloatSmall options;
     signoutoptionsbuttons signout,shutdown,restart;
     Dialog sign_out_dialog;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.modes);
        action_bar = getActionBar();
        action_bar.hide();
        welcome_headder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_notation);
        Intent welcome_headder_intent = getIntent();
        welcome_headder_string= welcome_headder_intent.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        welcome_headder.setText("Welcome, "+welcome_headder_string);

        options = (ButtonFloatSmall)findViewById(R.id.options_signout);
        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            sign_out_dialog = new Dialog(Modes.this);
            sign_out_dialog.setTitle("Signout options");
            sign_out_dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.shutdown);
            sign_out_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signout_options);

            signout = (signoutoptionsbuttons)sign_out_dialog.findViewById(R.id.signout);
            signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.remove("logged");
                    editor.commit();
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            });

        restart = (signoutoptionsbuttons)sign_out_dialog.findViewById(R.id.restart);
        restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new SnackBar(Modes.this, "This will Signout and restart the panel.Are yout sure you want to Restart the panel !","Yes",new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.remove("logged");
                        editor.commit();

                        try
                        {
                            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot" });
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Modes.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });


        shutdown = (signoutoptionsbuttons)sign_out_dialog.findViewById(R.id.signout_shutdown);
        shutdown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            new SnackBar(Modes.this, "Are you sure you want to shut down the panel", "yes", new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.remove("logged");
                    editor.commit();

                    try
                    {
                        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
                    }catch (IOException e)
                    {

                       Toast.makeText(Modes.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                   
                    }

                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
});
sign_out_dialog.show();

        auto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_auto);
        auto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent auto = new Intent(Modes.this,Auto.class);
                auto.putExtra("USERNAME",welcome_headder_string);
                startActivity(auto);
            }
        });

        manual = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_manualmode);
        manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent manual = new Intent(Modes.this,Manual.class);
                startActivity(manual);

            }
        });
        adminsettings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Adminsettings);

        savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            String value_username = savedInstanceState.getString("USERNAME"); //getting username key,value pairs sent from previous intents

            String value_password = savedInstanceState.getString("PASSWORD"); //getting password key,value pairs sent from previous intents

            if(value_username.equals("medequip") && value_password.equals("medequip")){   //Comparing username and password sent from previous intent activity to display admin settings button or not...

            adminsettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                          //setting visibility for a button

            }
            else
            adminsettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        adminsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent retriving_database = new Intent (Modes.this,AdminSettings.class);
                startActivity(retriving_database);
            }
        });





}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.modes, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my XMl:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.developer.milanandroid.Modes" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#FFC107">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="MODES"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="75dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_notation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_auto"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/automode"
                android:text="@string/automode" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_manualmode"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/manualmode"
                android:text="@string/manualmode" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttoncalibrationmode"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/calibration"
                android:text="@string/calibration" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_manualmode_2"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/manualmode"
                android:text="@string/manualmode" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Review"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/review"
                android:text="@string/Review" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Adminsettings"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/adminsettings"
                android:text="@string/Adminsettings" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

      <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloatSmall
        android:id="@+id/options_signout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:background="#FF8F00"
        android:drawable="@drawable/usr" >
    </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloatSmall>

   <!--   <com.gc.materialdesign.view.ButtonFloatSmall
        android:id="@+id/options_sign_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:background="#FF8F00"></com.gc.materialdesign.view.ButtonFloatSmall>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my custom dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.milan.paperbuttons.signoutoptionsbuttons
        android:id="@+id/signout"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp" 
        widget:paper_text="Signout"
        />

      <com.milan.paperbuttons.signoutoptionsbuttons
          android:id="@+id/restart"
          android:layout_width="350dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
          widget:paper_text="Signout and Restart " />s

      <com.milan.paperbuttons.signoutoptionsbuttons
          android:id="@+id/signout_shutdown"
          android:layout_width="350dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restart"
          android:layout_below="@+id/restart"
          android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
          widget:paper_text="Signout and Shutdown" />

      <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
          android:id="@+id/dialog_return"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/signout_shutdown"
          android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
          android:text="@string/back"
          android:textColor="#ffffff" >
      </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my logcat:

```
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): Process: com.developer.milanandroid, PID: 13445
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.developer.milanandroid/com.developer.milanandroid.Modes}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at com.developer.milanandroid.Modes.onCreate(Modes.java:132)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-02 10:22:30.070: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Line 132, your dialog is not initialized thus the nullpointerexception. It's obvious from your logcat...

Comment: I already initilized it dude @Wildcopper

Comment: You didn't in onCreate()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialized the dialog in the onClickListener(). Initialize it outside of it. That should fix it.

On a side note, don't add so much code in onCreate(). Try to have multiple methods. Will help in code readability.

Edit:
Create one method maybe named setupDialog(); remove the following lines which are present in your **options** variable's onClickListener implementation and add these to this newly created method.

```
sign_out_dialog = new Dialog(Modes.this);
        sign_out_dialog.setTitle("Signout options");
        sign_out_dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.shutdown);
        sign_out_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signout_options);

        signout = (signoutoptionsbuttons)sign_out_dialog.findViewById(R.id.signout);
        signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.remove("logged");
                editor.commit();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
```

Now, call the newly created before your **options.setOnClickListener** line.

Comment: I didn't get u dude can u tell me where i did the mistake.I am new to this@Jayesh Elamgodil

Comment: Thanks for patiently answering dude works prefectly...:)@Jayesh Elamgodil